# Tiled Web Map; what tile provider offer antarctic map tiles?

Tags: python, leaflet, tile-map-service, antarctica, jupyter-notebook

General Idea: I plot Sentinel-2 and Sentinel-3 images on a web map in a Jupyter Notebook using ipyleaflet. This works perfectly fine with the default Mercator projection. For images at high latitudes I use the [Arctic Web Map](https://webmap.arcticconnect.org/index.html#ac_3573/2/90.0/0.0) as follows:

```
tls = ipyleaflet.TileLayer(opacity=1.0,
                           url='https://{s}.tiles.arcticconnect.org/osm_3575/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', 
                           zoom=0, max_zoom=10)

m = ipyleaflet.Map(default_tiles = tls, zoom=6, center=[0,0])
```

This lead to a good result. Now I would like to do the same for the South Pole. Does anybody know a tile provider for projections like EPSG:3031?

Comment: What about WMS instead of TMS? For example there is a WMS providing LIMA data in EPSG:3031, could you work with that?

Answer (score 1):

The German OSM community provides a map at http://polar.openstreetmap.de/

I am not sure about its usage policy though. If you just use it in your private notebooks, it will be fine. But before you host something publically and expect some traffic, make sure to ask them beforehand!

Sideplug: Check out the amazing QGIS package http://quantarctica.npolar.no/